# Show/Hide multiple DIVs with same class name

Tags: jquery

I'm looping through a resultset which produces the following HTML:

```
 <tr>
    <td class="optionItems">
        Test<br />
        Test<br />
        <a href="#" class="description" >
            <img src="../../Images/Magnifying-Glass-icon.png"/>&nbsp;Description
        </a>
    </td>

    <td colspan="2" class="optionItemsLast">
        <input type="submit" value="Book" class="buttonGreen" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="optionItems">
        <div class="slidingDiv">
            Test><br />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have the following jQuery code to show/hide the div with the class name "slidingDiv":

```
 $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".description").show();

        $('.description').click(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });
```

When I click on any of the links with the "description" class name, all the divs show. I just want to only show the div corresponding the "description" link I clicked on.

I've tried something like this:

```
$('.description').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });
```

But with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you need a value for "slidetoggle", but what happens if you do:    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
            $('.description').click(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").show();
        });

Comment: not related but I suggest using div tables like here : http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
$('.description').click(function () {
     $(this)
        .closest('tr')       //get the closest tr
        .next()              //get the next row of that tr
        .find('.slidingDiv') //find .slidingDiv in next row
        .slideToggle()          
});
```

**Assumption:** That 2 tr are related and `.description` closest tr's next will be `.slidingDiv`'s tr

Answer (score 2):

You need to go all the way up the tree to the `tr` and then into the sibling `tr`:

```
$('.description').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: `.closest("tr").next()` should be `tr` if it is a valid HTML.

Comment: @Vega: I know, and debated... but I put it in anyway.  Plus, I have learned from SO that people sometimes use invalid html. :)  I'll take it out.